# How do I convert this such that numpy works on the entire list at a time?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Works fine using a single element/variable

```
import math
import numpy as np
from numpy import interp
```

Works fine for single value

```
t = 25
minVal = 0
maxVal = 100
```

Change the range from 0 to 100 to 0 to 1 using numpy

```
newT = interp(t ,[minVal,maxVal],[0,1])  
print newT

value =  math.sin(newT * math.pi / 2)
print value,'value'
>>0.25
>>0.382683432365 value
```

The above code worked fine and gave me the result for a single variable. Now I want numpy to do the same thing using lists as inputs, as numpy can work on the entire list, as I've used in other cases. How do I translate the above line to get numpy to operate on the entire list?

Now to operate on a list at the same time. I can't get the lines below to work. How do I use interp on the entire lists? How do I do the math on the entire list?

```
t= [25,25,25]
minVal = [0,0,0]
maxVal = [100,100,100]

converedMinVal = [0,0,0]
converedMaxVal = [1,1,1]
```

Change the range from 0 to 100 to 0 to 1 using numpy

```
newT = interp(t ,[minVal,maxVal],[converedMinVal,converedMaxVal])  

value =  math.sin(newT * math.pi / 2)
print value,'value'
```

Comment: `math.sin` only works with scalars, single values.  `np.sin` works with an array.

Comment: thanks Jpaulj  . how do I convert the line below to work with arrays ?             
      newT = interp(t ,[minVal,maxVal],[0,1])                  and             value =  math.sin(newT * math.pi / 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that needs to be changed is to make `t` an array and (as @hpaulj noted) use `np.sin()` rather than `math.sin()`, e.g.:

```
import numpy as np
import math

t = [10,20,30]
minVal = 0
maxVal = 100
converedMinVal = 0
converedMaxVal = 1
newT = np.interp(t ,[minVal,maxVal],[converedMinVal,converedMaxVal]) 
value =  np.sin(newT * math.pi / 2)
print value
```

... for which the output is:

```
[ 0.15643447  0.30901699  0.4539905 ]
```

(EDIT)

It appears that you may want `t[0]` to be interpolated in `[minVal[0], maxVal[0]]` and `t[1]` to be interpolated in `[minVal[1], maxVal[1]]` etc. In that case, you could use `scipy.interpolate.interp2d()`, which creates a function that interpolates in two dimensions, e.g. as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as spi
import math

t= [10,20,30]
minVal = [0, 11, 15]
maxVal = [100, 200, 500]
x = list(range (len(t)))*2
y = minVal + maxVal
converedMinVal = [0, 2, 10]
converedMaxVal = [1, 8, 20]
z = converedMinVal + converedMaxVal

f = spi.interp2d(x, y, z) 
newT = np.diag(f(range(len(t)),t))
value =  np.sin(newT * math.pi / 2)
print value
```

The function `f()` interpolates at all combinations of its two vector parameters and returns a matrix so if you only want interpolation at the time points in `t`, then you have to take the diagonal of that matrix, as I have done here.

I should note that the `scipy` approach is doing a lot more computation than is really necessary to solve this problem, but that might not be an issue in your case.

Comment: Thanks so much , can minVal and MaxVal be an array as well ? In my case both are arrays . When I use arrays for these values ... I get an error . How can I do find that ?

Comment: minVal and maxVal can't be arrays in `interp()`. Supposing they were, though, do I understand correctly that you want `t[0]` to be interpolated in `[minVal[0], maxVal[0]]` and `t[1]` to be interpolated in `[minVal[1], maxVal[1]]` etc.? You could do something like that with `scipy.interpolate.interp2d()`, which creates a function that interpolates in two dimensions.

Comment: Thanks Simon for sharing your knowledge , your understanding has been perfect and It’s been a tremendous help . Could you throw more light as to how I would I use scipy to do the same thing ... do I have to rewrite everything in scipy ? If it’s not too complicated and time consuming could you help with it ?

Comment: Thanks Simon .. that’s perfect ! Thanks for the help

Comment: @Josh: My pleasure. If any answer meets your needs, you can "tick" it to show that you've accepted the answer and/or upvote it.

Comment: how do I do that ? I cant find any tick button or upvote button ?

Comment: You can see how to accept an answer and/or upvote it at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: Done...Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function to iterate through those lists and provide you with the values.

```
def get_values(t_vals, minVals, maxVals):
    values = []
    for i in range(len(t_vals)):
        newT = interp(t_vals[i], [minVals[i], maxVals[i]], [0,1]) 
        value =  math.sin(newT * math.pi / 2)
        values += value
    return values
```

Comment: Thanks,I can iterate through the list but since numpy can work on lists, would like to use the speed of numpy rather than iterate large lists. Would prefer to use numpy to to work on the entire list rather than iterate through the list item by item